# Можно ли переписать условие в одну строку?

Tags: javascript

```
if (currentPos < min) {
  currentPos = min;
} else if (currentPos > max) {
  currentPos = max;
}
```

делаю так

```
currentPos = currentPos < min ? min : (currentPos > max ? max);
```

получаю ошибку

> Parsing error: ':' expected. eslint

Comment: Потому что для `(currentPos > max ? max)` не описано условие `:`

Comment: Это понятно, но его там и не должно быть

Comment: Должно. Если не соблюдается условие, то видимо значение равно само себе

Comment: currentPos = currentPos < min ? min : (currentPos > max ? max : currentPos); так?

Comment: В js отступы и переносы строк не играют роли, поэтому любой код можно переписать в _одну строку_, при этом **никак** его не меняя: `if (currentPos < min) {
  currentPos = min;
} else if (currentPos > max) {
  currentPos = max;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, переписать в одну строку можно.

Проблема решения в вопросе

```
currentPos = currentPos < min ? min : (currentPos > max ? max);
```

заключается в том, что опущена обязательная else-часть вложенного тернарного оператора, и это является синтаксической ошибкой.

С соблюдением синтаксиса, можно записать решение (например) так:

```
currentPos = currentPos < min ? min : (currentPos > max ? max : currentPos);
```

*«`min` если `currentPos < min`, иначе (`max` если `currentPos > max`**, иначе `currentPos`**)»* - чтобы соблюсти синтаксис, мы вынуждены указать последним "иначе"-значением текущее значение переменной, при невыполнении всех указанных условий совершая "бесполезное" присваивание (которое на самом деле никак не повредит).

---

**Оффтоп:**
Более читаемым вариантом в данном случае является использование методов `Math` вместо тернарника, как предлагает **@Алексей** в своем ответе:

```
currentPos = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, currentPos));
```

Поначалу это может показаться чуть сложнее для восприятия, но на самом деле все просто: сначала вложенный вызов вернет меньшее из `max` и `currentPos` (мысленно назовем эту величину `x`), а затем внешний вызов вернет большее из `min` и `x`.
Это читаемее и короче по символам, но выполняется медленнее тернарного оператора. Различие их быстродействия обычно имеет значение только в циклах с большим кол-вом итераций (в остальных случаях, этим различием можно пренебречь).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let number = 0;
let min = 1;
let max = 3;

console.log(Math.max(min, Math.min(number, max)));


number = 4;
min = 1;
max = 3;

console.log(Math.max(min, Math.min(number, max)));


number = 2;
min = 1;
max = 3;

console.log(Math.max(min, Math.min(number, max)));
```